# GitHub pull requests triggering all pipelines in Azure DevOps

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have 3 pipelines in Azure DevOps, on for each branch, and the code is on GitHub.

Whenever I do any Pull Request all my 3 pipelines get triggered. How can I avoid that?

The message says **"PR automated for"**

[image]

My 3 pipelines are using separated branches:

**develop pipeline**

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include: [develop]
  paths:
    include:
      - backend/*
```

**staging pipeline**

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include: [staging]
  paths:
    include:
      - backend/*
```

**production pipeline**

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include: [master]
  paths:
    include:
      - backend/*
```

Comment: Did you look at the YAML documentation? Specifically, the section that lets you define and control GitHub PR build behaviors?

Comment: I'll try `pr: none`, here in [PR trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#pr-trigger).

Comment: @DanielMann tx, I couldn't find it yesterday

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found in the docs [PR trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#pr-trigger) how to disable the run for all PRs adding:

```yaml
pr: none
```

It goes in the root like this:

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include: [develop]
  paths:
    include:
      - backend/*

pr: none
```

Also:

> Important
>
> YAML PR triggers are supported only in GitHub and Bitbucket Cloud. If
> you use Azure Repos Git, you can configure a branch policy for build
> validation to trigger your build pipeline for validation.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here,  would you please accept your solution as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)