# Exclude Azure Pipeline Runs From Github PR Status Checks

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Im currently in the process of moving our Pipelines from the Web UI to Yaml. And in doing so, i'm creating several stages for my pipeline.

The problem is that each of these stages are being shown on my pull request.
This includes a couple of stages that i use to resolve some variables that are used in later stages.

[image]
[image]

Is there any way for me to either exclude some of these steps, or explicit whitelist the ones i want shown? (I know that i can mark them as required before a merge is allowed)

Comment: Would this be what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62742570/3231778 let me know so can make it a dup

Comment: No, because this just triggers my pipeline, I want it to trigger, i just dont want all the stages shown as checks in github, as some of them are not important to the PR